# How do I hide installed apps in an AOSP build?

Tags: android, android-source

I need to hide an installed app (e.g. Settings, Calendar), in AOSP build, for example, the app shouldn't be listed in launcher to user. Any ideias?

Comment: I need to configure this before build, maybe this is possible by changing some .mk file but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the path for all the pre-loaded application. These apps can be removed from the `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` list.

***/device/qcom/common/base.mk***

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES := \
    Calendar \
    Settings \
```

This will remove the apk from the system image itself. If you want to remove only from the launcher then you may need to make changes in launcher app or either Calendar and Settings apps.